# [Fabric][Delta Tables] "Create database for [Lakehouse] is not permitted using Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric." How to solve this issue?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, fabric, delta-lake, data-lakehouse

I have a situation here on Fabric. I have a Workspace that was working just fine and I already have some notebooks on it and a few delta tables. Suddenly, whenever I try to run a query over my delta tables using a notebook I get the error: "Create database for [Lakehouse] is not permitted using Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric.".
It's also worth mentioning that I'm a guest in this Tenant I'm working on (don't know if this could somehow be related).

This error occurs regardless from which Lakehouse I use OR from which delta table I query; even if I create a new Lakehouse & table, I still face the same issue when querying it.
I tried to query the table using PySpark and also using SparkSQL, both show the same error message.
Below you can find similar queries to what I've tried:

```
%%sql
SELECT * FROM Lakehouse_Name.DeltaTable_Name LIMIT 100;
```

OR

```
df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM Lakehouse_Name.DeltaTable_Name LIMIT 1000")
display(df)
```

And here you can find the complete message:

```
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Create database for [Lakehouse_Name] is not permitted using Apache Spark in Microsoft Fabric.)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.withClient(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:111)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveExternalCatalog.createDatabase(HiveExternalCatalog.scala:193)
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SharedState.scala:165)
org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SharedState.externalCatalog(SharedState.scala:141)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.externalCatalog(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:54)
org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionStateBuilder.$anonfun$catalog$1(HiveSessionStateBuilder.scala:69)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog$lzycompute(SessionCatalog.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.externalCatalog(SessionCatalog.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.databaseExists(SessionCatalog.scala:340)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.requireDbExists(SessionCatalog.scala:262)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getTableRawMetadata(SessionCatalog.scala:597)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.catalog.SessionCatalog.getTableMetadata(SessionCatalog.scala:583)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2SessionCatalog.loadTable(V2SessionCatalog.scala:73)
org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.DelegatingCatalogExtension.loadTable(DelegatingCatalogExtension.java:73)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.super$loadTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:175)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.$anonfun$loadTable$1(DeltaCatalog.scala:175)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile(DeltaLogging.scala:141)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.metering.DeltaLogging.recordFrameProfile$(DeltaLogging.scala:139)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.recordFrameProfile(DeltaCatalog.scala:57)
org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog.loadTable(DeltaCatalog.scala:174)
org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogV2Util$.getTable(CatalogV2Util.scala:355)
org.apache.spark.sql.connector.catalog.CatalogV2Util$.loadTable(CatalogV2Util.scala:336)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$resolveRelation$3(Analyzer.scala:1350)
scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.$anonfun$resolveRelation$1(Analyzer.scala:1345)
scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:447)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$resolveRelation(Analyzer.scala:1332)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$14.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1195)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$$anonfun$apply$14.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1159)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:138)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1249)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1248)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.Project.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:69)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1249)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1248)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LocalLimit.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:1640)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$2(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren(TreeNode.scala:1249)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.UnaryLike.mapChildren$(TreeNode.scala:1248)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.GlobalLimit.mapChildren(basicLogicalOperators.scala:1619)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:135)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:323)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:134)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$(AnalysisHelper.scala:130)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:32)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1159)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveRelations$.apply(Analyzer.scala:1118)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$2(RuleExecutor.scala:222)
scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:126)
scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:122)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1(RuleExecutor.scala:219)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$execute$1$adapted(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:431)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.execute(RuleExecutor.scala:211)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$$executeSameContext(Analyzer.scala:231)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$execute$1(Analyzer.scala:227)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.AnalysisContext$.withNewAnalysisContext(Analyzer.scala:176)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:227)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.execute(Analyzer.scala:191)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.$anonfun$executeAndTrack$1(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker$.withTracker(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:93)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.rules.RuleExecutor.executeAndTrack(RuleExecutor.scala:182)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.$anonfun$executeAndCheck$1(Analyzer.scala:212)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.markInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:330)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer.executeAndCheck(Analyzer.scala:211)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$analyzed$1(QueryExecution.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.QueryPlanningTracker.measurePhase(QueryPlanningTracker.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$2(QueryExecution.scala:288)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:642)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.$anonfun$executePhase$1(QueryExecution.scala:288)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.executePhase(QueryExecution.scala:287)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.analyzed(QueryExecution.scala:118)
org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.assertAnalyzed(QueryExecution.scala:110)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.$anonfun$ofRows$2(Dataset.scala:99)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.ofRows(Dataset.scala:97)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sql$1(SparkSession.scala:640)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:827)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:630)
org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sql(SparkSession.scala:671)
org.apache.livy.repl.SQLInterpreter.execute(SQLInterpreter.scala:150)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$executeCode$1(Session.scala:801)
scala.Option.map(Option.scala:230)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.executeCode(Session.scala:798)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$execute$8(Session.scala:537)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.withRealtimeOutputSupport(Session.scala:1025)
org.apache.livy.repl.Session.$anonfun$execute$1(Session.scala:537)
scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
scala.concurrent.Future$.$anonfun$apply$1(Future.scala:659)
scala.util.Success.$anonfun$map$1(Try.scala:255)
scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:213)
scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$map$1(Future.scala:292)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.liftedTree1$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.Promise.$anonfun$transform$1(Promise.scala:33)
scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:64)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```